# Unusual and unidentified traffic from Android: Potential causes?

Tags: android, react-native, google-analytics, react-native-firebase

I have published an app on both iOS and Android, and since about a month ago, I have been receiving strange and unidentified traffic from Android:

1. On Google Analytics, lots of traffic from Android that has an average engagement time/session of 0m 00s, and an average engaged session/user of 0.02. These traffic have only three events logged per session: 'first_open' 'session_start', and 'screen_view', and nothing else.
2. These traffic are unidentified: 'undefined' for location, devices, etc.
3. On Google Play Console, daily app installs have stayed more or less the same for the same period. Thus, the traffic are not from actual app installs.

These have not happened at all on iOS.

[image]

I am using react-native and [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase), though I doubt this is relevant information for this case.

What might be the cause of this? Did anyone experience something similar? I have done my research, but could not find any useful reference for my case, so am writing here in the hopes of getting a clue.

Thanks!

Comment: Cheap Android phones are commonly used for fraud. Does your app send any SMS? Are the sessions coming from any particular locality? Do the users generating these sessions act otherwise like real users? Or, could there be an Android-specific bug that crashes on screen view?

Comment: @Abe my app does not send any SMS. The location is unknown, and they do not act like real users at all, just the three events I mentioned above are logged and the average session time is just 0.02s. No Android-specific bug that crashes immediately on launch. Any idea why this is happening?